# How to read Excel file starting from give row and column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xlrd

How can I read a excel file in pandas starting from a row and column, I am looking to drop some rows and columns, say my excel file contains some random data in starting rows and columns, so I would either like to begin reading at a given row,c column or drop few rows and columns. How can I achieve this ?

Typically I would like my rows to start from B21, drop everything till row 20 and Column A. 
Please help.

Comment: Hey there! Look for skiprows and usecols in the docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read your file as normal with the pd.read_excel command, to skip the first 20 rows you use the skiprows option and then drop the columns that you do not want. In this case that column will be columnAname.

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename', skiprows = 20).drop([columnAname], 1)
```